# How to create refresh/reload in Jtree / Jtable based file listing?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtree, .refresh

I read tutorial in [File Browser Gui](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) , but if the strucutre folder changed, program cannot dynamic reload, how to create refresh/reload function in File Browser GUI ?
Here my uncomplete code

```
refreshPath = new JButton("Refresh");
refreshPath.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        ....
     }
});
toolBar.add(refreshPath);
```

Answer (score 3):

- [FileIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) is low level and hard event for Java and Native OS too
- there are basically two ways

  a) [Watching a Directory for Changes for Java7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html), discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7784909/230513).

  b) use some of custom `FileIO Watchin`g (I can't suggest what's is better or not, maybe `FileWatcher by Apache`)
- in both cases nothing will be notified Swing GUI, have to notify by using `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread`
- by using `Runnable#Thread` ins't there guarantee that output will be notifyied `Event Dispatch Thread`, have wrapping output to the Swing GUI to the `invokeLater()`
- `SwingWorker` guarantee that, but for safer output you can to use `invokeLater()` too, we talking about 4th. short codelines moreover