# Filesystem JTree using Java 7's NIO

Tags: java, swing, java-7, jtree, treemodel

I've seen plenty of examples of [`JTrees`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) that display the file system using the standard Java [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API. Are there any example implementations of a JTree (maybe using a custom [`TreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html)) that use the new NIO apis from Java 7? I'd love to see an example that demonstrates proper usage of:

1. [`WatchServices`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to update the JTree when the file system is modified by another program or by the user
2. [`FileVisitors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) to get contents of the nodes
3. Asynchronous loading of tree node contents in case an operation takes a long time

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7784909/230513).